# Can't insert quotes around first item in concatenate formula using openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

Trying to write the following CONCATENATE formula to a cell. The cell value shows the formula except I need quotes inserted around the variable. When opening spreadsheet the cell shows a "#NAME?" error because the "" are not present around the column letter in the formula. I have tried multiple variations of double and single quotes and several other methods, but can't get quotes around column letter portion of formula when it is written to file.

```
ws.cell(row=7, column=2).value = "= _xlfn.CONCATENATE(" + str(ws.cell(row=7, column=2).offset(row=0, column=daq_sp_col_offset).column_letter) + ",INT(C13/B16))"

cell result = =CONCATENATE(BJ,INT(C13/B16))
```

Comment: Concatenate doesn't need prefixing. Simplify your code by calculating BJ outside of the fomula.

Comment: Thank you @Charlie Clark, your suggestion is doable but doesn't really "simplify" coding. A whole new block of code will need to be written to calculate multiple column letter answers. I am creating a summary section based on positional references dependent on 3 data frames imported to the spreadsheet. These data frames are all differing in row length and may in the future change in column width. I mostly just wanted to know if it was possible to add the quotes with the code I posted, that there wasn't some obvious answer I had missed.

Comment: I don't see what the provenance has to do with the unreadable code. Mix single and double quotes if you need one or the other in the result.

Comment: I am new at this but have an honest question. I realize the line of code is long and cumbersome, but the .cell methods are straight from the doc's, why is it "unreadable" code? I made a solid effort using a host of variations with quotation marks, quad/triple/double/single/escaped etc. Basically anything that didn't throw a syntax error or make the column letter method be written as part of the string, otherwise I never would have posted here.

Comment: You should include the desired result in your question. Ideally this what Excel itself writes in XML, because what you see in the editor is often not the way the formula is actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

Using an intermediate variable makes the code easier to read and debug.

```
src = ws.cell(row=7, column=2)
target = src.offset(column=dap_sp_col_offset)
formula = "=CONCATENATE('{}', INT(C13/B16))".format(target.column_letter)
```

This should be compared with a comparable formula from a sample file.

Comment: thank you. I actually found a similar solution with an intermediate variable that required only one additional line of code. Turns out the combination of quotation marks I was looking for was, '"' (single-double-single) surrounding the column letter retrieval.  This solved getting the quotes around the column letter in the cell formula.

Comment: The number of lines isn't important, readability is. But glad you got things working.